# Checkebox Checked or Unchecked giving same message

Tags: jquery-mobile

Intending to check weather the checkbox is checked or not . In both the cases , if the checkbox is checked or unchecked , i am getting the message checked . Is it the right way to handle this checking or there is some other way.

```
if ($('#SaveCheckbox').attr('checked') != true)
{
 console.log('Checked');
}
 else
{
  console.log('Unchecked');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this code ,use  `:checked` attribute and is condition

```
if ($('#SaveCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
     console.log('Checked');
} else {
     console.log('Unchecked');
}
```

Comment: Thanks , it Worked ! And to set a value for checkbox ie checked or unchecked ?